# Expert preferences to use Express generator to create Express boiler plate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, express

I have a straightforward question to be answered. Is it preferable for a beginner to use the express boilerplate by using the express generator?

I know it's dumb to ask such a question but it's stopping me from writing my own boilerplate to initiate any project. So, I need to know what should be the best practice to adopt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

Where you need express-generator

- If you are willing to use a template engine like ejs, hbs.
- If you are willing to use traditional web architecture (Cookie-based authentication, vanilla HTML)

If you are going to use modern web architecture with token-based authentication and use a frontend framework like Reactjs or Vuejs, Configuring those things manually is very easy than using express-generator.